# Just another issue with form validation in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have the next issue:

I have some custom form which fills one - `MyCustomDto`.

```
public class MyCustomDto
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(Email)]
    public String Email {get;set;}

    [Required]   
    public String Name {get;set;}

    ...
    //ETC
}
```

I have the controller action that works with entire data from form:

```
public JsonResult WorkWithMyCustomDto(MyCustomDto request)
{
    ....
}
```

And I have the function in JS that sends the Ajax request to this action of controller:

```
function PassTheData()
{
   //Some ajax request to the action of controller.
   $.ajax(....);
}
```

I dont want to use submit behaviour. The question is how to validate form before sending ajax request? The validation should be made by the data anotation of class `MyCustomDto`. Thx for any advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use the Unobtrusive Client Validation in the ASP.NET MVC. It will automatically generate some custom attribute like data- in HTML elements based on the Data Annotation that decorated on your View Model. The reference link [here](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html).

Answer (score 1):

Inside your JS-function you should validate the form manually:

```
function PassTheData()
{
   var validator = $("#myform").validate();

   if(validator.form()){
        // the form is valid
        //Some ajax request to the action of controller.
        $.ajax(....);
    } else{
        // the form is invalid
        //validator.errorList contains an array of objects, where each object has properties "element" and "message".  element is the actual HTML Input.
    }

}
```

For a complete reference on the jQuery validator-plugin check out the documentation-pages:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: the .valid() function will validate the form by the data annotation of the my c# class? Also the question, how to get the information which field failed to validate?

Comment: Yes, that is, if you're using the standard jQuery/MS validation JS. I've edited my answer so you can get access to the validation errors. For a full reference check the jQuery validate documentation

Comment: But how about the validation error message? Jquery will put the error to the @Html.ValidationMessageFor(...) by it's self?

Comment: Well, not exactly by itself. In the standard MVC template you will see that there are two plugins: jquery.validate and microsoft.unobtrusive.validation (I don't remember the exact names). The MS script will plug into jQuery validation and the Html-helper in turn plugs in to the MS-validation. It's possible that you need to make some small changes to my code (I don't have an editor available ATM to test it), but conceptually this is what's happening. Give it a try and if you have more questions, feel free to add them here.